# How to get an argument for link_to dynamically from the site rails 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, unobtrusive-javascript

I am using a the link_to method in Rails the unobstrusive jQuery way:

```
<%= link_to "save", 
            update_elements_diagram_path(diagram, :shown_elements => ["speed", "position_break"]),
            :method => :post, :remote => true, :class => "close",
            :onclick => "stringViewsTableLoading()" %>
```

This works. But now I want to get the arguments "shown_elements" dynamically from the users inputs.
I know how to get them from the form to javascript, but how from javascript to Rails?

```
 ... shown_elements => "getShownElements()"
```

or something similar would be great.

Greetings

Sandro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I see what you mean there, so I guess that you somehow have a few fields on your page, and that what you want is to get the value of those fields in the `:shown_elements`.

This is not how it's supposed to be done. Think the other way around. You are posting a form using `:method => :post`, which means that those will be accessible in your target controller using `params[]`.

```
def DiagramsController < ApplicationController

    def update_elements
        shown_elements = params[:shown_elements] # or something like this.
    end

end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Seems that I didn't see the wood for the trees, That worked. Thx.